# MySQL spatial index doesn't work when equating MBRContains() to TRUE?

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL query that seems to be producing correct results but according to `EXPLAIN` isn't using the spatial index and so is taking much longer than necessary to return all the rows.

```
SELECT * FROM listings2
WHERE MBRContains(    GeomFromText('POLYGON((32.653132834095 -117.40548330929, 32.653132834095 -117.06151669071, 32.942267165905 -117.06151669071,32.942267165905 -117.40548330929,32.653132834095 -117.40548330929)    )')  ,geoPoint)=true
```

Interestingly, I figured out that if I remove the `=true` and let the `MBRContains()` stand alone, the spatial index gets used properly.

**My question is: why is this the case, and can I do something to enable the spatial index to work even when I have `=true` written at the end of the `WHERE` clause?**

**And the only reason I have `=true` in there at all is because I'm using CodeIgniter's Active Record and can't see an easy way around it (so if you know a way around it, that's another way of solving my problem).** (Even switching to just use `$this->db->query()` would involve a lot of work.)

My table is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings2` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `latitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `longitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `geoPoint` point NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
      KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
      SPATIAL KEY `geoPoint` (`geoPoint`)
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=404838 ;
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: How do you pull the specs of the table?

Comment: @JimThio, I'm not see what you're asking, but see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: say you have a table. How do you use phpmyadmin to show that CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `listings2` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `latitude` decimal(10,6) NOT NULL,
      `longitude` decimal(1 ... bla bla thingy

Comment: @JimThio, in the left panel, click the table that you want the schema of, then click its Export tab, then uncheck the Data checkbox, then click Go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced a similar problem while writing a query in hibernate. Here is how I worked around it: [Hibernate and MySQL spatial index](http://code.vith.me/2011/11/hibernate-and-mysql-spatial-index.html)

All I did was register a new function with a tiny bit of hack in the MySQLDialect of our application:

```
registerFunction("mbr_contains", new SQLFunctionTemplate(Hibernate.BOOLEAN, "MBRContains(?1, ?2) and 1"));
```

And then I used this function in the HQL query. The query now became something like this:

```
... and mbr_contains(GeomFromText(:${boundaryVariable}), location) = 1 ...
```

which is valid HQL, and also generates SQL which makes use of the spatial index:

```
... and MBRContains(GeomFromText(?), location) and 1 = 1 ...
```

Comment: I have not verified that this would help me, since my question is a couple years old and I'm not working on this anymore, but it seems to be the best answer (since it's the only one!). Thanks.